# Angular App Heroku Deploy - Application Error h10 status = 503

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, npm

I have been trying to deploy my Angular 7 app to Heroku for a couple days now and keep encountering Application errors after build is successful.  I realized i had my entire /dist folder in .gitignore, so I removed it but I still encounter application errors.   I check the heroku logs ("Failed at start script") and this was the error that jumped out at me, and not sure how to proceed:

> TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null:
>   dist/hockey-app at Function.create ()  at
>   Function.serveStatic [as static]
>   (/app/node_modules/serve->static/index.js:48:21) at Object.
>   (/app/server.js:7:23)

here is what the node_modules/serve->static/index.js looks like: at the line indicated:

```
// copy options object
  var opts = Object.create(options || null)
```

Edit: Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/hockey-app')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/hockey-app/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('running'));
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hockey-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.4",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your server.js file now... The `express.static()` method shouldn't accept what your passing it.

Try using `path.join(__dirname, "path/to/index")` and then pass that full path to the static method.

Comment: dist was added to my git already. As far as Procfile, i don't have one.  Is this something that is supposed to be created upon build?  Or do I just add one myself?

Comment: No problem. Was that the issue?

Comment: its what you said, I was using the path.join incorrectly.